# Average in VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, average

I am new to VBA in excel. I have a range of data with 11 000 numbers. I want to calculate the average of first 60, then next 60 until the end. I did some programming but it isn't working. Can someone please help me with it?

```
Sub Hourlyaverage()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l  As Long, m As Long
    
    Sheets("DUT1_Test51_excel").Select
    
    i = 3
    j = 3
    k = 63
        
    Do While Cells(i, 12).Value <> ""
        
        l = Cells(i, 12).Value
        m = Cells(k, 12).Value
        
        Cells(j, 20).Value = [Average (l : m)]
        i = i + 60
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 60
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look closely at what you're trying to do in this code:

```
l = Cells(i, 12).Value
m = Cells(k, 12).Value

Cells(j, 20).Value = [Average (l : m)]
```

You're assigning a "long" value to each of `l` and `m` and then calling them in the average function as if they were references to a cell.

I suggest that you add a range variable, assign the *location* of the data you want to average and use that as your function argument.

Something like:

```
Dim myRange as Range

'Loop code here
Set myRange = Range("L" & i & ":L" & k)
Cells(j, 20).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(myRange)
```

Comment: Should the last line be:
Cells(j, 20).Value = Application.WorkSheetFunction.Average(myRange)

Comment: Yep, edited in the answer. Thanks for catching it.